# How to fix 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'?

Tags: c#, datagridview

first off sorry to ask how to fix this error (i know its a common question) but i am quite new to C# and I cannot seem to find a solution for it.

I am making a windows form that imports data from an excel file and displays it in a DataGridView. When executing I get the error:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: No value given for
>   one or more required parameters."

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class CurrentOrders : Form
    {
        public CurrentOrders()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CurrentOrders_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void BackBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NewOrder NewOrd = new NewOrder();
            this.Hide();
            NewOrd.Show();

        }

        private void DataGridViewLOG_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Tombies\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\PCSsheet.xls" + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
            (
                "SELECT DATE, CUSTOMER, PO, COMMENTS, PCS FROM [LOG$]", conn
            );

            DataSet DsOrderLOG = new DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            conn.Open();
            Adapter.Fill(DsOrderLOG);
            conn.Close();
            DataGridViewLOG.DataSource = DsOrderLOG.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```

I know it has something to do with the 'Adapter.Fill' at the bottom, but from there on I'm lost.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`Date` is probably the culprit.  Try putting it (an all other column names, for that matter) in brackets:

```
"SELECT [DATE], [CUSTOMER], [PO], [COMMENTS], [PCS] FROM [LOG$]", conn
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it still gives the same error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: You're positive those column names are correct in the Excel file?

Comment: Yep I just double-checked them all.